# How to call Strategy pattern based on incoming type

Tags: algorithm, go, design-patterns

I have 2 strategies. According to the data from the request, I want to call the strategy I want and perform operations in a single line. How can I achieve this? So far my code is like this

```
package strategy

type Strategy interface {
    Distribute(request model.RouteRequest) (*model.DistributeResponse, error)
    GetStrategyType() int
}
```

```
package strategy

type Strategy interface {
    Distribute(request model.RouteRequest) (*model.DistributeResponse, error)
    GetStrategyType() int
}
```

```
package strategies

import (
    "github.com/x/internal/enum"
    "github.com/x/internal/model"
    "github.com/x/internal/repository"
)

type DistributeBranchStrategy struct {
    repo repository.Repository
}

func NewDistributeBranchStrategy(repo repository.Repository) *DistributeBranchStrategy {
    return &DistributeBranchStrategy{
        repo: repo,
    }
}

func (d *DistributeBranchStrategy) Distribute(request model.RouteRequest) (*model.DistributeResponse, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func (d *DistributeBranchStrategy) GetStrategyType() int {
    return enum.BRANCH
}
```

```
package strategies

import (
    "github.com/x/internal/enum"
    "github.com/x/internal/model"
    "github.com/x/internal/repository"
)

type DistributeTransferCenterStrategy struct {
    repo repository.Repository
}

func NewDistributeTransferCenterStrategy(repo repository.Repository) *DistributeTransferCenterStrategy {
    return &DistributeTransferCenterStrategy{
        repo: repo,
    }
}

func (d *DistributeTransferCenterStrategy) Distribute(request model.RouteRequest) (*model.DistributeResponse, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func (d *DistributeTransferCenterStrategy) GetStrategyType() int {
    return enum.TRANSFER_CENTER
}
```

MY service:

```
package service

import (
    "github.com/x/internal/model"
    "github.com/x/internal/repository"
    "github.com/x/internal/strategy/strategies"
)

type DistributeService struct {
    repo                     repository.Repository
    distributeBranchStrategy strategies.DistributeBranchStrategy
}

type Distribute interface {
    Distribute(vehicleNumberPlate string, request model.DistributeRequest) *model.DistributeResponse
}

func NewDistributeService(repo repository.Repository, strategy strategies.DistributeBranchStrategy) *DistributeService {
    return &DistributeService{
        repo:                     repo,
        distributeBranchStrategy: strategy,
    }
}

func (d *DistributeService) Distribute(vehicleNumberPlate string, request model.DistributeRequest) *model.DistributeResponse {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    for _, x := range request.RouteRequest {
        d.distributeBranchStrategy.Distribute(x)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Years ago I made an operation using make[] . I was able to create the relevant strategy and perform the operations by matching it with an enum according to a parameter in the request. I can't remember it right now, I couldn't find any examples on the internet. Can you help me?

Comment: Where in the code are you to decide which strategy to use? The service is written to work with a specific type of strategy

Comment: The service receives a request. There is a parameter in Request and let's call it x. X; It can be 1, 2, 3. I wrote enums for them and the getStrategyType function shows which type they belong to in the strategies. Here is my request: I will return request in the for loop and call strategy according to this X parameter and take action.

Comment: You can define a global `var strategies=map[int]Strategy`, and call `strategies[x]`, after making sure `x` is a valid number.

Comment: Can you give an example of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all available strategies in a map:

```
var strategies = map[int]func(repository.Repository) Strategy {
   enum.BRANCH: func(repo repository.Repository) Strategy {
      return NewDistributeBranchStrategy(repo)
   },
   ...
}
```

Then call:

```
s, ok: = strategies[x]
if !ok {
  // error
}
s(repo).Distribute(...)
```